# Update vagrant user-id

Tags: vagrant, homestead, userid

I'm using vagrant for many projects.

The web-service and php-service is running with the user vagrant(uid:1000). I'm using OS X with nfs to sync my shared-folder with vagrant. At the guest-system all files get my OS X user-id as owner.

So I want to update the vagrant user to the uid 501. But if I use `usermod -u 501 vagrant` I get an error because the user is used by a process.

I hope that someone can help me.